# AWS service to expose key/value pairs to EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, environment-variables

Is there a centralized AWS service to expose key/value pairs to EC2 instances easily?

I'd prefer a way that either exposes as a https endpoint, or injects them into environment variables without requiring using the aws-sdk.

Comment: Best bet's probably an ElastiCache Redis instance.

Comment: Would I have to use the aws-sdk or application code to fetch? I'd prefer something I can retrieve via shell scripts.

Comment: https://github.com/caquino/redis-bash should do the trick.

Comment: DynamoDB is an excellent key/value store that is available over HTTPS.  However, to access it using shell scripts you would need to use the AWS CLI, which technically is different from the AWS-SDK so I'm not sure if this would work for you.

Comment: If you use CloudFormation you could either use the [UserData](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-userdata) property or use an [`AWS::CloudFormation::Init`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) resource to pass key/value data in.